# Does TCP/IP connection automatically closed when OS do a garbage collection after a thread end?

Tags: c, sockets, memory-management, port, tcp

I got confused when write a C program...

The program I wrote is a client end program, its function is quite simple, it just sends requests to the server end.

I initialized a socket in my program to communicate with the server. I think what I should do is to disconnect and destroy this connection before the thread ends. Otherwise it will cause a memory leak. Because although OS will do memory cleaning of my thread, it only clean the memory which assigned to my program, I think the socket won't be disconnect.

But I found a strange thing... After my program ends, from my server end, I use -netstat command to see the port status. This socket will closed immediately, my server's timeout is 60 seconds and I set keep-alive of the socket property... I tried to sleep 5 seconds in my client program, and found the socket stay established.

I thought in this scenario, in my server's view, this socket wouldn't close immediately but wait for a timeout...

So is the port on my client end released? who did it? and who noticed my server to disconnect this socket? I don't know...

So could anyone who knows this tell me something about it? 
Thanks so much

Comment: The OS doesn't "Garbage Collect"... definitely not "pre thread"... but, when a process is terminated, all the resources attached to that processes are released, including memory allocations, open files etc'.

Comment: Your program cannot properly implement the TCP protocol, that protocol does not permit abrupt aborts without proper handshaking.  Properly ending a connection is one of the more convoluted operations in TCP.  You are seeing the OS take care of that job.

Comment: OS manages process resources, not thread resources. Open files, connections, memory and everything else are tied to a process.

Comment: What state is the socket in, according to Netstat?  TIME_WAIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on situation once process end kernel will send connection close message if suppose kernel doesnt get response back it will go to time wait state and it will remain there for few minute.if it got response connection will get close immediately.Basically in your case you are geting resp thats why socket is geting close.take tcpdump and check you will come to know.